# div with % width and px border

Tags: css, html, width, border

I'm trying to create a div with 3 divs inside.

```
    .outter
    {
        right: 100px;
        border: 10px solid white;
    }
    .main
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .left
    {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: green;
        border-right: 5px solid white;
    }
    .center
    {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        border-left: 5px solid white;
        border-right: 5px solid white;
    }
    .right
    {
        float: right;
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: orange;
        border-left: 5px solid white;
    }



<div class="outter">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="left">
        </div>
        <div class="center">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I got so far. 
-The parent div should have a right distance fixed of 100px, a border of 10px white and the widht is the 100% - 100px;
-The inside divs have 40% + 40% + 20% with a distance between them of 10 px (thats why I putted the border-left 5 and border-right 5.

[image]

I'm having problems setting this. What I need is to have fixed sized borders and margin to the right. the other divs should be dynamic to fullfill the 100% width.

Can anyone help me?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `box-sizing` for this. write like this:

```
.main,
.main >*{
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ubtdT/

Comment: that's it! that's what I was trying to achieve. thanks sandeep.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with the [box-model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). An element cannot have 100% width and then a 10px border, because the border is added outside the 100% width, which is causing your problem.

Depending on what browsers you intend to support, you can make use of CSS3's [box-sizing](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/) property. By setting `box-sizing: border-box;`, you can force the browser to instead render the box with the specified width and height, and add the border and padding inside the box. Which should solve your problem. Note the limited support in older browsers.

If you want to go even more experimental you can use the new CSS3 `calc()` to actually calculate a dynamic width:

```
/* Firefox */
width: -moz-calc(75% - 100px);
/* WebKit */
width: -webkit-calc(75% - 100px);
/* Opera */
width: -o-calc(75% - 100px);
/* Standard */
width: calc(75% - 100px);
```

Comment: " An element cannot have 100% width and then a 10px border, because the border is added outside the 100% width, which is causing your problem." exactly. Thanks Christofer. I'm going to try/study this new css3 calc() but first I need to get this done!